# NoClassDefFoundError when implementing OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

I am trying to implement a photoviewer using fragments with fullscreen/normal view.
See API sample with activity here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ContentBrowserActivity.java

But I have noticed a strange bug on android versions < honeycomb.
When I implement OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener inside my fragment, application crashes with NoClassDefFoundError. On android 4 everything works well.
Is there a workaround for this bug?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    PhotoViewPager viewPager = new PhotoViewPager(getActivity());
    viewPager.setTag("photoViewPager");
    viewPager.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            int diff = mLastSystemUiVis ^ visibility;
            mLastSystemUiVis = visibility;
            if ((diff & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE) != 0
                    && (visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE) == 0) {
                setNavVisibility(true);
            }
        }
    });
    return viewPager;
}
```

Stacktrace

```
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12708): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.ex.android.main.photos.photo.PhotoFragment$2
 at com.ex.android.main.photos.photo.PhotoFragment.onCreateView(PhotoFragment.java:87)
 at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener.html) was introduced in API level 11.

Therefore, you should put the change listener code in a compatibility wrapper.